# IXSLTemplate::putref_stylesheet returns E_INVALIDARG

Tags: c++, xml, msxml, xslt

Well, it's been several hours I'm lost...

`IXSLTemplate::putref_stylesheet` doesn't document any error except E_FAIL.

However in my case `putref_stylesheet` returns `E_INVALIDARG`. `GetErrorInfo()` is only redundant telling me that the "Argument is invalid". So I am not left with much information.

However my code is pretty close to all examples I found on the web and msdn.
And it does something like:

```
void xsltProcessing(MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocument* pXmlDoc, MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocument * pXslDoc)
{
    IXSLTemplatePtr pTemplate;
    pTemplate.CreateInstance( _T( "Msxml2.XSLTemplate" ));
    pTemplate->putref_stylesheet(pXslDoc);
    //...
}
```

As there is not much documentation for `putref_stylesheet`. Do you have any idea what could go wrong for it to return `E_INVALIDARG` ?

My `pXslDoc` is a `IXMLDOMDocument` I have loaded from static const strings with success.

Any clue ? ( I guess it's pretty vague a question, but it's been hours I am searching )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you loading `pXslDoc` asynchronously perhaps?

The default behaviour for `IXMLDOMDocument` objects is to load asynchronously, so it is possible that the `pXslDoc` has not finished loading when you call `putref_stylesheet()`.

Adding the following code before you load `pXslDoc` would fix this problem, if it is what you are suffering from:

```
pXslDoc->put_async(VARIANT_FALSE);
```

Comment: Yes. I did it because I saw it on the examples on the net, but without knowing why. Thanx you for the explanation.